# Unstage something from the last commit

Tags: magit

Let's say I just did a commit with changes to two files. Now I would like to have just one of the files in that commit, and I would like to stash the other file. So, in essence, I would like to soft reset, unstage one of the files, recommit with the same message (or maybe change it). And after all that, I will have the second file not committed, and I can stash it, or stage it and commit it anew or whatever.

I used to do that in GitX easily, by just clicking the `amend last commit` checkbox. It would show the staged changes, the commit message etc, and I could just change the message, or stage more, unstage some, etc.

Is there an easy way to do that in magit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I will have the second file not committed, and I can stash it, or stage it and commit it anew or whatever.

The quickest way to get this in magit is hit <kbd>RET</kbd> on the top line of the status to show the `HEAD` commit, then in the `*magit-revision` buffer hit <kbd>u</kbd> on the part you don't want in the commit (this can be a whole file, a hunk, or even part of a hunk; and you can do this multiple times).  Then <kbd>c e</kbd> (or <kbd>c a</kbd> if you want to edit the commit message) to remove the part(s) from the commit.  This requires `magit-unstage-committed` to be set to `t` (the default) to allow `magit-unstage` to fallback to `magit-reverse-in-index` on committed hunks.

---

You can also literally follow the sequence you outlined in magit:

> I would like to soft reset,

<kbd>X s</kbd> `HEAD~1` <kbd>RET</kbd> (If point is on the commit you want to reset to, then it's the default input, and you don't need to type it).

> unstage one of the files,

Navigate to the unstaged file (<kbd>j u</kbd> jumps to unstaged section), then <kbd>u</kbd> to unstage it.

> recommit with the same message (or maybe change it).

<kbd>c c</kbd> then <kbd>M-p</kbd> to retrieve previous message when the COMMIT_EITMSG buffer pops up.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thank you.  
The second part is what I am trying to avoid, but I didn't know about `M-p`.  
The first part is very close to what I wanted. I will probably make a function out of it, that does the slow parts without me typing, like the going-to-revision-of-last-commit part. Other than that, cool stuff :)

Comment: So the going-to-revision-of-last-commit, I can do by hitting `RET` on the `Head:` line on the top of the main magit buffer. Thanks to C-Keen from the emacs irc channel for that.